# Python appending to a sublist in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of empty lists as such:

```
some_lists = [[]] * 3
[[], [], []]
```

I want to append an integer to the first sublist:

```
some_lists[0].append(1)
```

But it appends the integer 1 to all the sublists and generates:

```
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

How do I append elements individually to the sublists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a reference to every sublist in the list. Instead, you can use a list comprehension:

```
some_lists = [[] for i in range(3)]
some_lists[0].append(3)
```

Output:

```
[[3], [], []]
```

Comment: Did not know that. Thank you for the quick answer. :)

Comment: @CharvakKondapalli glad to help!